# Python - sys.stderr not getting saved to .txt or .log

Tags: python

I was checking the working of standard streams, and currently I am working with `stderr` using python. To explain clearly, the following is my code:

```
print("Python")
testt()
```

when I run the code I get the following:

```
Python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python34/s3.py", line 5, in <module>
testt()
NameError: name 'testt' is not defined
```

Now I wanted to save the error message to a text file, so my code for that was as follows:

```
import sys

sys.stderr = open('err.txt', 'w') # I tried with 'err.log' also
print("Python")
testt()

sys.stderr.close()
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
```

Now when I run the program, the error is not being displayed in the python shell. It is not getting saved to the `err.txt` file also.

When I checked the `err.txt` file properties it shows that the file has been modified recently (i.e. the time when the program was run), but the file is blank. What might be the problem? I am using windows and python 3.4.

---

I installed python 3.5 and still get the same issue. I also tried using contextlib, but still unsuccessful. My modified code using `contextlib` is as follows:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr

with open('C:/Users/Jeri_Dabba/Desktop/Shortcutz/test/outfile.txt', 'w') as file, redirect_stdout(file):
    help(pow)

with open('C:/Users/Jeri_Dabba/Desktop/Shortcutz/test/errfile.log', 'a') as file1, redirect_stderr(file1):
    testt()
```

`redirect_stdout(file)` was working fine, it was saving the output to the file; whereas `redirect_stderr(file1)` is not saving the `stderr` to the file.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Works for me, are you running your code in Python Shell?

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574702/how-to-print-to-stderr-in-python)

Comment: No, I am running it as a separate .py file.

Comment: Well, then it might work if you're not running it in Python Shell. However I'm using Python 3.5 and it works.

Comment: Hey, maybe delete `sys.stderr.close()` and `sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__`?

Comment: @KevinGuan I tried deleting, but the same problem.

Comment: Hmm...Can you redirect `sys.stdout` to file?

Comment: Yeah, that was working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `sys.stderr` was never closed. When `testt()` errors, the program exits -- just the error message is redirected. So the file was blank.